# What is "grade" option?

Tags: snap

I am building a snap package and snapcraft prints the following warning:
"grade" property not specified: defaulting to "stable"

What is the "grade" option and how does it relate to channels?

Comment: According to [this recent commit](https://github.com/snapcore/snapcraft/commit/2e97ae2f44abec06c35102afdd91ccf15e5685b9) of snapcraft, the 'grade' property refers to "the quality grade of the snap" and can be 'devel' or the default 'stable'.

Answer (score 10):

`grade` can be either `stable` or `devel` and it essential tags the resulting snap for life with the grade it should have.

How is this useful? Imagine you are developing a snap and have CI setup to always push to the `edge` channel; in this case one would set `grade: devel` and what this does is ensure that this snap is not accidentally published to the stable channels.

A snap with `grade: devel` cannot be released to the `stable` or `candidate` channels.

For full documentation on the topic check [publish your snap](http://snapcraft.io/docs/build-snaps/publish)